# Show website as startmenu tile

Tags: windows-10, live-tiles

I have a small webpage which shows me some information.

Is it possible to put it as tile into the windows 10 startmenu?

http://localhost/zeit.php

[image: http://localhost/zeit.php]

Comment: If you want to have a shortcut to the web page pinned to start menu - that is possible. If you want to have information displayed on webpage to be shown on a dynamic live tile in start menu - that is not possible. It can be done only if you write/create Windows metro app that parses the data from webpage and shows in on live tile.

Comment: Sure. Answer posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible understanding of your question:

If you want to have a **shortcut** to the web page pinned to start menu - that is **possible**.

If you want to have **information** displayed on webpage to be **shown on a dynamic live tile** in start menu - that is **not possible**.

It can be done only if you write/**create** Windows **metro app** that parses the data from webpage and shows it on live tile.